# Как программно на Visual C++ выполнить чтение файла с подключённого к компьютеру USB mass storage device (например, флэшки)?

Tags: usb, visual-c++, файлы

Я написал на Visual C++ диалоговое приложение MFC в MS VS 2013 Ultimate под Windows 7 Максимальная. Моё приложение выполняет обнаружение подключения/извлечения, в частности, флэшки. Для этих целей в программе отлавливается сообщение `WM_DEVICECHANGE`, а в функции `OnInitDialog()` вызывается функция `RegisterDeviceNotification()`.
В моём приложении выполняются примерно следующие шаги:

1. Вызывается `SetupDiGetClassDevs()` для получения дескриптора (`HDEVINFO`) информации класса устройств.
2. Вызывается `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo()` для перебора информации о каждом из устройств в пуле информации, на который ссылается `HDEVINFO`. В каждой итерации цикла, мы получаем информацию об очередном устройстве, записанную в буфер типа `SP_DEVINFO_DATA`.
3. Внутри каждой итерации вызывается `SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId()` для получения идентификатора экземпляра устройства в формате: `USB\Vid_04e8&Pid_503b\0002F9A9828E0F06`.
4. Если полученный идентификатор экземпляра устройства соответствует таковому для устройства, которое сгенерировало событие `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` или `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE`, то тогда вызывается функция  `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty()` для получения читабельного имени этого устройства или его описания.

Моя проблема в том, что мне требуется запрограммировать чтение файла с флэшки, в том случае, если программа зафиксировала подключение флэшки (т.е. произошло событие `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL`). Как мне сделать это чтение средствами Visual C++?

Comment: Просто не разу с флэшкой не имел дела. Как, например, в программе определить букву, идентифицирующую том флэшки?

Comment: Это если буква есть. Юзер может отключить букву для данного девайса. Так что вопрос не лишён смысла.

Comment: Может дадите ссылку на пример именно для моей ситуации или близкий к моей ситуации?

Comment: @user3769902: Судя по всему, вот релевантный пример: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Учтите, что на одном USB-устройстве может быть **много** томов, и не все они могут иметь букву.

Comment: @user3769902: Учтите, что нотификации по поводу устройства могут приходить повторно, а также по несколько устройств одновременно.

Comment: @user3769902: Возможно, вам нужно после `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` вызывать [`SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), что даст вам mount point для вашего тома. Имея mount point, вы можете передавать его в [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: VladD, скажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего нотификации от устройства могут приходить повторно?